# Ruby on Rails optional route segments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create two routes in my Rails application with optional parameters.

Here's my routes file:

```
get '(a)(/:area_id/)l/:location_id/(*url_title)', to: 'locations#show', as: :location
get 'a/:area_id/(*url_title)', to: 'areas#show', as: :area
```

Navigating to the following URLs correctly routes me to the right controller:

```
http://localhost:3000/a/1/l/2/seo-friendly-title.html
http://localhost:3000/a/1/seo-friendly-title.html
```

However, navigating to this url does not work:

```
http://localhost:3000/l/2/seo-friendly-title.html
```

I receive a `No route matches` error. Is it possible to make the `a/:area_id` portion optional when the `l/:location_id` portion is present?

Using `Rails 4.2.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add another route...

```
get 'l/:location_id/(*url_title)', to: 'locations#show'
```

There's no reason why two routes can't map to the same action.